# How can I convert a result into a list of variables that I can use as an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I was able to come up with these two parts, but I'm having trouble linking them.

**Part 1** - This accepts a filter which is listed as 'project = status = blocked'. This will list all issue codes that match the filter and separate them line by line. Is it necessary to convert the results into a list? I'm also wondering if it converts the entire result into one massive string or if each line is a string.

```
issues_in_project = jira.search_issues(
    'project = status = Blocked'
)

issueList = list(issues_in_project)

search_results = '\n'.join(map(str, issueList))

print(search_results)
```

**Part 2** - Right now, the jira.issue will only accept an issue code one at a time. I would like to use the list generated from Part 1 to keep running the code below for each and every issue code in the result. I'm having trouble linking these two parts.

```
issue = jira.issue(##Issue Code goes here##)

print(issue.fields.project.name)
print(issue.fields.summary + " - " + issue.fields.status.statusCategory.name)
print("Description: " + issue.fields.description)
print("Reporter: " + issue.fields.reporter.displayName)
print("Created on: " + issue.fields.created)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1

`'project = status = Blocked'` is not a valid JQL. So first of all, you will not get a valid result from calling `jira.search_issues('project = status = Blocked')`.

The result of `jira.search_issues()` is basically a `list` of `jira.resources.Issue` objects and not a `list` of `string` or lines of `string`. To be correct, I should say the result of `jira.search_issues()` is of type `jira.client.ResultList`, which is a `subclass` of python's `list`.

#### Part 2

You already have all the required data in `issues_in_project` if your JQL is correct. Therefore, you can loop through the `list` and use the relevant information of each `JIRA issue`. For your information, `jira.issue()` returns exactly one `jira.resources.Issue` object (if the issue key exists).

#### Example

```
... # initialize jira

issues_in_project = jira.search_issues('status = Blocked')

for issue in issues_in_project:
    print(issue.key)
    print(issue.fields.summary)
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you Chris!